# How to add browser based node in eko studio code editor

Tags: javascript

```
 /**
 *
 * @function onReady
 * @param {InterludePlayer} player
 * @param {object} ctx
 */

function onInit(player, ctx) {
    ////////// START YOUR CODE HERE \\\\\\\\\\
    //Akshay Chordia//

    var viwer = player.repository.get('node_viewer_as_subject_61d930');

    // nodeend()
    // if(Playlist.slice(-1)[0].==='node_viewer_as_subject_61d930')
    var browser=function(){

         if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1 ) 
    {
        return 'node_opera_f63acb';
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 )
    {
        return 'node_chrome_dad33d';
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1)
    {
        return 'node_safari_5274d7';
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) 
    {
         return 'node_firefox_f9bd96';
    }
    else if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )) //IF IE > 10
    {
        return 'node_nchrome_c63059'; 
    }  
    else 
    {
        return 'node_no_browser_a6ccc3';
    }
    };

    viwer.addPrefetch(browser());
    // Visit http://developer.eko.com for detailed API documentation
    //////////  END YOUR CODE HERE  \\\\\\\\\\
}

export default {onInit,
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTq7W.png)

This is code written in studio code panel(app.js).

It seems fine to me but it's not working. I even changed oninit to onready.

It's also not connecting to next node. I used prefetch function on viewer node (nodeid="node_viewer_as_subject_61d930") and nodeID for prefetch  to be returned by the function browser.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps check the spelling of "viewer", e.g. `var viwer = player.repository.get`